# How to properly use geocube geom parameter with crs other than 4326

Tags: python, extents, rasterization, geocube

I dont fully understand how to use the "geom" parameter in python geocube library with crs different than 4326, described here: https://corteva.github.io/geocube/stable/geocube.html#make-geocube

Could anyone please show me, how to use the geom parameter with crs 3857, while taking the bbox from other raster layer, or set of coordinates? I can't seem to get the syntax of specifying the different crs right... I think the documentation is missing a clear and simple example. I am rasterizing a point gdf and need the raster to be snapped to some other raster with the given bbox...

````
bbox = (-9907392, 5160736, -9795746, 5311946)

geo_grid = make_geocube(
       vector_data=gdf,
       measurements=["rasterize"],
       geom = json.dumps(mapping(box(???))),
       output_crs="epsg:3857",
       resolution=(-2, 2),
       fill=0
   )```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: geocube docs]

```py
bbox = (-9907392, 5160736, -9795746, 5311946)
geom = mapping(box(*bbox))
geom["crs"] = {"properties": {"name": "EPSG:3857"}}
geo_grid = make_geocube(
   vector_data=gdf,
   measurements=["rasterize"],
   geom=geom,
   output_crs="epsg:3857",
   resolution=(-2, 2),
   fill=0
)
```

Comment: Thanks, it isn't really clear from the documentation.

Comment: Contributions are always welcome to improve the documentation.